# MySQL query- insert value in select query

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have the following MySQL query

```
cHandler.execute("select analog_log.value from packet_log where parameter_id in (378, 379, 380, 381);")
```

I'm querying a remote database and there's a possibility that the remote DB does not have an `analog_log.value` for a certain `parameter_id`. In this scenario, I would have 4 or lesser number of values to insert into the local DB. This leads to an error when trying to insert <4 `analog_log.value` into 4 columns in the local DB.

If no `analog_log.value` is present for the corresponding `parameter_id`, is it possible to insert a value (say -315) in the query result so that I have 4 values to insert into the local DB?

Comment: As I understand: you are getting 4 rows from remote DB and then inserting the values as columns in local DB. In this case I think you can check the values in application(python) and then insert the required value for the missing values from remote DB

Comment: How do I make sure the dummy value is inserted into the  column corresponding to the right `parameter_id`?